# Unable to redirect to new page using angular.js's $location or $window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, redirect

I am developing my first app using angular.js (v 1.6.3) and I am stuck on a very basic problem. I have created a list page for "User Group", and on this list I have a Edit button. On click event of this edit button, I want to redirect the record id to edit page. 
Below is code for my button:

```
<button data-ng-click="editUserGroup(userGroup.id)">&#9998;Edit</button>
```

Below is the code for `editUserGroup`

```
$scope.editUserGroup = function(userGroupId) {
    //$location.path("/userGroup.html").search({c:'edit', id:userGroupId});
    //$scope.$apply();
    $window.location.href = './userGroup.html#/?c=edit&id='+userGroupId;
}
```

In short, I want to redirect to edit page and also need to pass 2 parameters,
`?c=edit&id=<actual id here>`

As you can see in my above code, `$location.path()` not working as it is not reloading new page, rather changing the URL only like `<Some URL>/listUserGroup.html#!/userGroup.html?c=edit&id=1`. If I use `$window.location.href`, I can redirect to new page but `#/` is getting HTML encoded like below
`<Some URL>/userGroup.html#!#%2F%3Fc=edit&id=1`

How should I redirect to new page and pass both the parameters using angular.js?

Comment: Are you using any router? If not, use one) With i.e. ui-router you can simply add <button ui-sref="editStateName({c: edit, id: userGroupId})"

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I am not using any router. I will give it a try tomorrow and will update you. By the way, my app is not SPA, do I still need routing? Thank you.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what is SPA and when/how it should be used. If your want to load completely new page all the time (not from user perspective, but from server perspective) angular is not for choice. Everything after # is ignored by server -- you can check in network tab that it is simply not sent at all by browser.

Comment: ohhkk. In this case, I think storing the data in sessionStorage is better for me. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, taking hint from comments, I used `window.location` to redirect the page to next, and used `window.sessionStorage` to store the data I want to send to next page.